# HTTP Get & Post code with slow performance

Tags: java, android, http, https

I had developed an application in which I hit several URLs and show data on mobile. But the problem is that it requires more time. If I check the same URL on Firebug tool I get a response in 2-3 seconds, but the same URL requires 8-15 seconds on mobile.  In my Android application I am using HTTP get and post method as follows:

```
public InputStream httpGetResponseStream(String url, String request) {
connectionUrl = url;
InputStream response = null;
try {
    processGetRequest();
    HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(host, get);
    response = httpresponse.getEntity().getContent();
} catch (Exception e) {
    response = null;
}
return response;
}

public InputStream httpPostResponseStream(String url, String request) {
connectionUrl = url;
InputStream response = null;
try {
    processPostRequest();
    if (request != null) {
        InputStreamEntity streamEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(request.getBytes()), request
                        .length());
        post.setEntity(streamEntity);
    }
    HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(host, post);
    response = httpresponse.getEntity().getContent();
}catch (Exception e) {
    response = null;
}
return response;
}

private void processGetRequest(){
    uri = Uri.parse(connectionUrl);
    String protocol = connectionUrl.substring(0, 5).toLowerCase();
    if (protocol.startsWith("https")) {
        securedConnection = true;
    } else {
        securedConnection = false;
    }
    if (securedConnection) {
        host = new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), 443, uri.getScheme());
    } else {
        host = new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), 80, uri.getScheme());
    }
    get = new HttpGet(uri.getPath()+query_string);
}

private void processPostRequest() {
uri = Uri.parse(connectionUrl);
String protocol = connectionUrl.substring(0, 5).toLowerCase();
if (protocol.startsWith("https")) {
    securedConnection = true;
} else {
    securedConnection = false;
}
if (securedConnection) {
    host = new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), 443, uri.getScheme());
} else {
    host = new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), 80, uri.getScheme());
}
post = new HttpPost(uri.getPath());
}
```

Any suggestion to improve code will be appreciated

Comment: Without inspecting the code: Could it be that your mobile is slower in bandwidth and hardware processing power?

Comment: @tb- thanks for suggestion yes, mobile is slower in bandwidth and hardware processing power but still there is any change that I should make in code so speed will increase.

Comment: Try using `HttpUrlConnection` instead of `HttpClient`. [Android's HTTP clients](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)

Answer (score 5):

I personally haven't used anything HTTP-related in Java yet, and thus can't talk about your performance. What I can see though is the following code:

```
if(protocol.startsWith("https"){
    securedConnection = true;
} else {
    securedConnection = false;
}
```

I will assume you have `securedConnection` as a private classwide field, so I won't talk about the fact that you only use it to determine the port in the method scope.

the fun thing is, your code could be written in one line:

```
securedConnection = protocol.startsWith("https");
```

if you now inline protocol (Eclipse <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>) you get following line:

```
securedConnection = connectionUrl.substring(0,5).toLowerCase().startsWith("https");
```

you see that the call to substring is unneccesary.

---

You also have a large duplication in itself with the methods `processPostRequest()` and `processGetRequest`. they are actually exactly the same apart from the last line:

```
get = new HttpGet(uri.getPath()+query_string);
post = new HttpPost(uri.getPath());
```

you might want to move them into a method like this:

```
private enum Type{
    GET, POST
}

private HttpRequest processRequestOfType(Type t){
   uri = Uri.parse(connectionUrl);
   securedConnection = connectionUrl.toLowerCase().startsWith("https");
   host = securedConnection ? new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), 443, uri.getScheme())
              : new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), 80, uri.getScheme());
   request = t == Type.GET ? new HttpGet(uri.getPath()+query_string) 
              : new HttpPost(uri.getPath());
   return request;
}
```

---

Lastly I saw that in your method `httpGetResponseStream()` you have the parameter request, which is never used in the code you posted.